# Multiple Windows ( or Multiple Boxes actings as psuedo multi window ) in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Hello I am new to python, but I do have some experience in Visual Basic

I am trying to code a (preferably as cross-platform as possible) program in Python with the 'pygame' library, and I want it to have several different simultaneous windows.

I have looked extensively on the internet for ways to do this, with many different options, but no results. My attempts have been such:

1. I originally tried to find a way to make multiple windows but a similar question on this site clarified that as a result of pygame being based off of SDL, this was not possible, thus I had to "fake" it.
2. My second idea was to have one big transparent window with smaller surface objects within to give the illusion of multiple windows, but no matter what I tried (transparency key, surface alpha, filling with a transparent colour) the window remained a thoroughly non-transparent black.
3. The third idea I found was again to "fake" transparency by taking a screenshot of the image behind the window and putting that as the surface object background, but I have not found a way to code that.

So my question is how I might be able to create/fake a multiple window program? Yes, tall order I know, but to make it taller, may I ask that you explain any possible answers with a decent amount of explanation?

P.S. Bonus Points if you can find a way so that when the "transparent" part of the display surface is clicked, the whole thing minimizes (so far the only ways I've found draw a rectangle around the desired target and check for collisions but that wouldn't work for me as that would be triggered anywhere you click)

EDIT: Any possible solutions do not have to be specifically in pygame, I just mentioned that so that you might appreciate what libraries I'm working with

EDIT: Thank you user 3424423 for your answer, I have installed PyQt and I am able to take screenshots, save them to a directory and blit them to the pygame window. The only problem I have is that the screenshot includes the program's own window, I coded it so the first image is taken before the window is created, but even then, afterwards the screenshots displayed on the window will include itself, so its not truly 'transparent'. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not possible to make something similar with pygame. Pygame does **not** support multiple windows, neither does it to make screenshots or transparency. You have to go to another package. I suggest PyQt. It's cross-platform too.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but as the window is a pygame surface object, would another package work with it?

Comment: Or were you suggesting a complete replacement of pygame with PyQt?

Comment: What I thought was a complete replacement... I don't know if it's possible to blit surfaces of other packages on a pygame display, I work on a higher layer :)

Comment: well I had been working with python v3.2.5, but I'm trying out python v2.7.8 with pyqt and pygame (i would like to keep pygame as it is highly recommended for creating 2D games)